# Why isn't PTIJ on Upcoming Events?

Tags: discussion, events

PTIJ is a pretty important event in Mi Yodeya. I'd expect that if Yat Shevat makes the calendar, PTIJ should get some attention, too.

Is there a reason that PTIJ isn't highlighted on the sidebar with Upcoming Events? Or is this just an oversight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PTIJ season is long enough that people will be amply notified of it by seeing questions pop up. It's not so important that it needs additional announcement.